# Android Studio XML symbols no longer linking correctly

Tags: xml, android-studio

I was creating layouts in XML for an Android project, and I pressed Alt+Enter+Enter one too many times. Now the style="@style/my_style" symbols no longer link to the styles, and are in a thin black font. They don't also don't go red if the style doesn't exist.

I've changed a setting somewhere, but I don't know what to look for. I tried deleting the .iml and .idea folders, but no change.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: Go to Preferences > Editor > Language Injections, and remove the additional rules you've added by clicking the minus sign at the bottom.